# Cohen–Macaulayness of $k[[x^2, x^3, xy, y]]$ over $k[[x^2, y]]$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and $R = k[[x^2, y]]$ and $S = k[[x^2, x^3, xy, y]]$. Since $R \subset S$, is $S$ Cohen–Macaulay as $R$-module?

To check this, what I have observed is that in $S$, the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is $\langle x^2, x^3, xy, y\rangle$, and the dimension of $M$ is $2$. From here, I cannot proceed to check the depth. My goal is to check whether the depth and the dimension are same or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S=k[[x^2,x^3,xy,y]]$ is not a Cohen-Macaulay module over $R=k[[x^2,y]]$. If it were, then $y$, $x^2$ would be a regular sequence on it. But in $M/yM$, the element $xy$ is non-zero, but is killed by $x^2$ (similarly in $M/x^2M$, $x^3$ is non-zero but is killed by $y$, so $x^2$, $y$ is not a regular sequence on $M$). See Bruns and Herzog, "Cohen-Macaulay Rings", Section 2.1, especially Theorem 2.1.3 (a).

Another way to see this is that as a module over $R$, $S$ is isomorphic to $R\oplus \mathop{\rm Rad}(R)$, and $\mathop{\rm Rad(R)}$ is not a Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module.

I apologise for my previous, now deleted remark to the effect that $S$ was a free module of rank two over $R$. It clearly isn't - I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: The depth of $S$ is one, and the projective dimension is one, thus satisfying the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula.